# Add a new column to 'Create New Order' Page

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

I am wondering which files I need to edit in order to add a new column to the products list displayed when Creating a New Order.

Specifically I wish to filter by Attribute Set Name, exactly as you are able to on the Catalog > Manager Products page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml file in your custom module. For this open admin layout xml of your custom module and write below code:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
    <reference name="items_grid">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>companyname/modulename/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>

<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
    <reference name="items_grid">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>companyname/modulename/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_items>
    <reference name="items_grid">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>companyname/modulename/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_items>
```

Then copy adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml to adminhtml/default/default/template/companyname/modulename/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml

Write following in grid.phtml thead and tbody to add your new column:

```
 <thead>
         <tr class="headings">
             <th><?php echo $this->__('My custom column title') ?></th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('companyname_modulename/adminhtml_blockname', '', array('item' => $_item))->setTemplate('companyname/modulename/sales/order/create/blocktemplate.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
```

Hope this helps!!